# vue-router I want to use hash '?' to repalce '#'

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

- in vue-router I want to use hash '?' to '#'

The Stack Overflow site engine, as you know, uses Markdown for questions and answers. Per the Markdown specification, you are allowed to freely intermix HTML and Markdown tags.

Answer (score 0):

from the [vue-router source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/history/hash.js), you can see that it is hard coded to use '#'.